# Is There a Connection String For Connecting to Client Machine

Tags: c#, sql-server

I installed a windows form application on a client computer but when I try to log into my application it gives me this error:

> a connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: shared memory provider, error: 0- No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

This is a c# windows form application running with SQL Server database, with login details. I have added the in and out bound rule on my firewall, I have tried changing my connection string severally, I have enabled tcp/ip port with its default port number, I have tried using the same network for both computers, I have tried using window and sql authentication, I have disabled firewall on client computer

Here is my connection string

```
<add name="connstrng" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AnyStore;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

I expect to be logged in to my application on the client computer using the same database with my server computer.

Comment: Are you sure about the correctness of this string against MySql ? MySql doesn't support the Integrated Security key. Please show the code where you use this string.

Comment: That's a SQL Server connection string, connecting to a database on the *local* machine. The error says that there's no database running on the local machine.

Comment: That connection string needs no login details, it uses Integrated Security, which means it connects using the current user's account. To connect to a remote server specify the correct server name or IP in the `Data Source` property

Comment: That's a SQL Server connection string; see https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/ for how to construct a MySQL connection string.

Comment: @steve yes am sure, it works on my local machine but it doesn't on my client machine, am using the string on app.config

Comment: Let's us understand the main point here. Are you using MySql or are you using Sql Server? You have tagged this question with _MySql_ but everything here seems to point to an Sql Server database instead.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ok, I tried modifying my connection string but i can't connect to my local database, am sure it will not work on the client machine. i also tried my ip address, here is my connection string '<connectionStrings>
  <add name="connstrng" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-5I8JFS0\EMEKA;Initial Catalog=AnyStore; User ID=adminpos;Password=***********" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Comment: @steve am using microsoft sql server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i found the solution i changed my connection string and its working fine now, thanks guys.
here is my connection string-

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="connstrng" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-5I8TFY3\EMEKA;Initial Catalog=AnyStore;User ID=adminpos;Password=********" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If you found a solution, you should post its details so as to help other people who may be experiencing the same problem, otherwise you should [edit] your question and add the text of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Connection strings are usually defined within the Web.config file.  As @Panagiotis Kanavos said, the string is connecting to a local data source, which should work as expected within your dev environment.  The web.config file should be located within the root directory of your project.  Edit this file on the client's machine to point to the expected server / database.  You may want to keep a blank or default version of this file in source control to avoid overwriting other's connection string info.

Example String:

```
<add name="SomeDB" connectionString="Data Source=snapdragon\SQL2k14;database=DBNAME;User Id=username; password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Edit: "snapdragon" would be the host computer name. "SQL2k14" would be your sql server instance.

Comment: A windows forms application doesn't have a `web.config` file.

Comment: pls its a window app, not a web app it uses app.config not web.config

Comment: @mr_ceejay, @Jake is still correct. Even if it's `app.config` and not `web.config`, the file structure is the same.

Comment: i tried that also, this time i cannot connect with my local machine and sure it wouldn't work on a client machine.